# Global variable in class

Tags: javascript

I have a below-class Square,

Now the count variable is in Global space irrespective of Square class,

Can I declare the count variable inside the class to make it a class global variable?

```js
count=0;
class Square{
    constructor(sides){
    this.sides = sides;
    count++;
    }
    getArea(){
    count++;
    return this.sides*this.sides;
    }
    setSides(sides){
    count++;           
    this.sides = sides;
    }
    static getCurrentSides(){
    return count;
    }
}
const square = new Square(20);
console.log(square.getArea());
square.setSides(8);
console.log(square.getArea());
console.log(Square.getCurrentSides());
```

Comment: You can declare a variable inside the class to make it a class-level variable

Comment: The term you are looking for is _static member_ (which is a synonym for _class global variable_) ... which you already used for `getCurrentSides()`. So just add `static count = 0;` on top of your class

Comment: @devnull69 but can you change value of static member ?

Comment: yes, of course you can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the `count` variable to be non-global. This could mean two things. Either you want it to be accessible from outside but not on the global object (`window` in browser contexts) or you want it to be inaccessible from outside the class.

If it’s the first, you can declare it inside the class but make it static:

```js
class Square {
    static count = 0
    constructor(sides){
        this.sides = sides;
        Square.count++;
    }
    getArea(){
        Square.count++;
        return this.sides*this.sides;
    }
    setSides(sides){
        Square.count++;           
        this.sides = sides;
    }
    static getCurrentSides(){
        return Square.count;
    }
}

const square = new Square(20);
console.log(square.getArea());
square.setSides(8);
console.log(square.getArea());
console.log(Square.getCurrentSides());
```

This way, `Square.count` will still be accessible (readable and writable) wherever `Square` is accessible.

If you want `count` to be entirely private, you can create a block-scoped variable:

```js
let Square;
{
    let count = 0;
    Square = class Square {
        constructor(sides){
            this.sides = sides;
            count++;
        }
        getArea(){
            count++;
            return this.sides*this.sides;
        }
        setSides(sides){
            count++;           
            this.sides = sides;
        }
        static getCurrentSides(){
            return count;
        }
    }
}

const square = new Square(20);
console.log(square.getArea());
square.setSides(8);
console.log(square.getArea());
console.log(Square.getCurrentSides());
```

The same could also be accomplished using a private static field, but that’s only recently become available so support may vary:

```js
class Square {
    static #count = 0
    constructor(sides){
        this.sides = sides;
        Square.#count++;
    }
    getArea(){
        Square.#count++;
        return this.sides*this.sides;
    }
    setSides(sides){
        Square.#count++;           
        this.sides = sides;
    }
    static getCurrentSides(){
        return Square.#count;
    }
}

const square = new Square(20);
console.log(square.getArea());
square.setSides(8);
console.log(square.getArea());
console.log(Square.getCurrentSides());
```

Comment: First case in your answer is what I was looking for.